# How can I fix my Epson Stylus TX101 Multifunction Printer to print, scan, and copy?

Tags: printing, scanning, epson

I have multifunction printer (Epson Stylus TX101), I can print but can't scan .... any solution for my problem ? (I already try using wine and install scan program from Epson CD - not work, using simple scan and Xsane - not detected.)

Answer (score 2):

Your model number isn't specifically listed here, but if you want to try there are several .deb files you could attempt to install to get this piece of hardware working. It'd be a total shot in the dark, but it may be worth your time.

http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/lsb/epson-inkjet/escp/

Answer (score 0):

This is a driver problem. Your device is yet to be supported by SANE. I have the same problem with my Canon MP-258. Try to find sane packages from your manufacturer website.